# PL/SQL Function How to show salary after increases and salaries that have increased above 10,000

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sal_increase 
    (p_salary f_emps.salary%TYPE, p_percent_incr NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
    RETURN (p_salary + (p_salary * p_percent_incr / 100));
    END;

SELECT last_name, salary, sal_increase(salary, 5)
FROM f_emps;
```

The above QUERY displays last_name, salary (before increase), sal_increase.

what if I want to display a select statement, only employees who get a salary after the increase above the value of 10000?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzDQY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cteSalaries AS (SELECT f.LAST_NAME,
                            f.SALARY AS OLD_SALARY,
                            SAL_INCREASE(f.SALARY, 5) AS NEW_SALARY
                       FROM F_EMPS f)
SELECT c.LAST_NAME,
       c.OLD_SALARY,
       c.NEW_SALARY
  FROM cteSalaries c
  WHERE c.NEW_SALARY > 10000
```